How to block time using external calendars in Google Calendar?
Our company uses Google Workspace for mail and calendars. I have added my private Google account's calendar as an external calendar in my company's calendar to show "busy" slots.
Unfortunately, when any of my team mates creates a meeting in Google Calendar and goes to "find a time," it only shows blocked slots from my company calendar, completely ignoring the external private calendar.
Can I make sure my private appointments are considered when my teammates try booking a time slot with me?

You'll need to add your work account as an attendee of your personal account events. It's like you have two different people's calendars and thee is no connection between the two.

Yup, that was it. Thanks!

I managed to solve this by writing an AppScript to duplicate my private events into a separate org calendar in the company and auto-adding the user email as attendee.

Can you share that script with us?
